# How to use the device orientation plugin in Ionic2 / Angular2

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2, device-orientation

How to use the [device orientation in Ionic2 / Angular2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-orientation/), in order to create a compass. How does this plugin work, are there any examples. And does it work at all))
I installed this plugin and use it on the android emulator or I use the application * .app on the device, but nothing happens. Very little information about how to work with this plugin in Ionic2/Angular2 and create an application.

Comment: [How to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can find find full explanation of usage in the README inside the plugin's github page (that is linked in this page you mentioned): https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation

Comment: It's not really suitable for writing to a typescript, for me

Comment: @ChristianBenseler is right, you should read the official readme. The ionic-native wrapper only gives you an interface to work with the plugin in typescript, the underlying features and how it works are described in the readme. Besides, the basic usage is described on the ionic-native page. Try to add logs in different places and then check the console to see what parts of your code don't get executed.